# Performing multiple regex matches to same index with pymongo

Tags: python, mysql, mongodb, pymongo

I need to translate some MySQL to mongodb. I have a MySQL query with multiple regular expression matches on one column. Is it possible to do the same thing with mongodb?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 REGEXP r1 AND column1 REGEXP r2 AND colum1 REGEXP r3;
```

With pymongo I can perform regex searches with single regex like so:

```
regex1 = re.compile(r1)
db.collection.find({"column1":regex1})
```

or

```
db.collection.find({"column1":{"$regex":"r1"}})
```

How do I add multiple regexes on column1?

These do not work:

```
{"column1":regex1,"column1":regex2}
{"column1":{"$regex":"r1","$regex":"r2"}}
{"column1":[regex1,regex2]}
{"column1":{"$regex":["r1","r2"]}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
db.collection.find({"column1": {"$all": [re.compile("r1"), re.compile("r2")]}})
```

Also take a look at future [$and operator](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1089).

BTW unless your regexp is prefix-like (`/^text/`) the index [won't be used](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions).